# Openflow controller in java?

Tags: java, routes, switching

i am new to Openflow but what i read is that it provides user to modify flowtables in switches to change routing and for this purpose we use a controller.

Now for my project, i have to develop a controller or may be use some existing and modify it as per research requirements. From what i have seen NOX is most famous contorller but it is written in C++ and i am not good in C++ so i wanted to opt for a java based option. Most openflow frameworks i think offer full simulation environment where we can also create switches/firewall etc, but in my project i already have physical nodes that support openflow feature.

With this in mind, can you please recommend me a simple java based Openflow controller that i should use to be able to contorll traffic flow in these nodes??

Comment: why am i given negative vote? any explanation please??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Floodlight from Big Switch Networks. It is quite stable, and is being tested in production by Big Switch.

http://floodlight.openflowhub.org/

Comment: thankyou Lalith, apparently this is what i have started using in my thesis project, and things are going pretty good now, thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can also try Beacon which Floodlight forked from, see: http://www.beaconcontroller.net/

Comment: Is it easy to code beacon? or flood light?
for someone with fair java knowledge which should be the preferable controller choice?